# How to get actual memory size required for lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I have a very large file that can vary in size. It has entries of the form: `nnnn,yyyy-mm-dd,xx.xxxx` where, `nnnn` is an integer, `yyyy-mm-dd` the year, month and day, and `xx.xxxx` a floating point number. The size of `nnnn` can vary in length from a single digit to > 9 and most importantly, all of the entries must be kept in memory in a list. Each list element is a tuple of the form `('nnnn','yyyy-mm-dd','xx.xxxx')`. I need to know *a priori* how large a list my memory can handle.

Is there any python tool that can give the actual memory size of this list (in bytes) as the tuples created from each line are appended to it?

Please run the following code and it should be obvious that sys.getsizeof() does not give the **acutal memory size occupied** -- at least with python 3.6.5

```
import sys

tuple1 = ('1234','2019-04-27','23.4658')
tuple2 = ('1563','2019-04-27','19.2468')
klist1 = [tuple1]
klist2 = [tuple1,tuple2]
print (sys.getsizeof(klist1))
print (sys.getsizeof(klist2))
```

Comment: Do you want the actual memory size of the list and all the objects contained in the list?

Comment: [Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) is Raymond Hettinger's deep sizeof recipe. It handles several subtleties that would be involved here (doesn't double count the same object, avoids going into reference cycles, etc). Otherwise, you have to estimate this yourself if you want to know ahead of time. It's relatively easy to produce a worst-case estimate.